# Compress and decompress string with zlib.net in c#

Tags: c#, zlib

I am using zlib.net in c# to compress and decompress string.

This is my code

```
class GZOutputStream : ZOutputStream
{
    public GZOutputStream(Stream in_Renamed) : base(in_Renamed)
    {
        byte[] dictionary = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sDictionary);
        z.inflateSetDictionary(dictionary, dictionary.Length);
    }

    public GZOutputStream(Stream in_Renamed, int level) : base(in_Renamed, level)
    {
        byte[] dictionary = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sDictionary);
        z.deflateSetDictionary(dictionary, dictionary.Length);
    }
}

public static byte[] compressString(string source)
{ 
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes (source);

    MemoryStream memOutput = new MemoryStream ();
    GZOutputStream zipOut   = new GZOutputStream(memOutput, zlibConst.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);

    zipOut.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    zipOut.finish();

    memOutput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    byte[] result = memOutput.ToArray();

    return result;
}

public static byte[] deCompressString(string source)
{ 
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes (source);
    MemoryStream memOutput = new MemoryStream ();
    GZOutputStream zipOut   = new GZOutputStream(memOutput);

    zipOut.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    zipOut.finish();

    memOutput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    byte[] result = memOutput.ToArray();

    return result;
}
```

When I compress a string, it works well. However, when I decompress the result string of the compress function, there is an exception :

> ZStreamException: inflating:
>   zlib.ZOutputStream.Write (System.Byte[] b1, Int32 off, Int32 len)

So what's the solution?

Comment: What's the exception you get when you decompress the string?

Comment: ZStreamException: inflating: 
zlib.ZOutputStream.Write (System.Byte[] b1, Int32 off, Int32 len)

Comment: There's no more information than that returned in the exception (i.e. what the actual problem is)?

Comment: only the ZStreamException. I cannot decompress the to target string.

Comment: What is sDictionary? The above code doesn't compile.

Comment: it's a string like "abcdef".

Comment: I find that when the dictionary is short(one character) , the program works well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string DeCompressToString(byte[] buffer)
    {
        MemoryStream memOutput = new MemoryStream();
        ZOutputStream zipOut = new ZOutputStream(memOutput);

        zipOut.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        zipOut.finish();

        memOutput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] result = memOutput.ToArray();

        var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);

        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just providing code isn't an ideal answer, because the asker can't learn from it. Please add some context, and comments, to explain what you're doing, and why!

Answer (score 0):

5 year old question, I know, but for anyone still looking (and I was), the problem is that the Write method in ZOutputStream returns **zlibConst.Z_NEED_DICT** after the first call to **z.inflate** and that's when the dictionary needs to be supplied.  So you need to override the Write method, test for that return and supply the dictionary at that point...

```
public override void Write(System.Byte[] b1, int off, int len)
    {
        if (len == 0)
            return;
        int err;
        
        z.next_in = b1;
        z.next_in_index = off;
        z.avail_in = len;
        do
        {
            z.next_out = buf;
            z.next_out_index = 0;
            z.avail_out = bufsize;
            if (compress)
                err = z.deflate(flush_Renamed_Field);
            else
                err = z.inflate(flush_Renamed_Field);

            if (err == zlibConst.Z_NEED_DICT)
            {
                int y=z.inflateSetDictionary(dict, dict.Length);
                err = z.inflate(flush_Renamed_Field);
            }

            if (err != zlibConst.Z_OK && err != zlibConst.Z_STREAM_END)
            {
                throw new ZStreamException((compress ? "de" : "in") + "flating: " + z.msg);
            }
            ms.Write(buf, 0, bufsize - z.avail_out);
        }
        while (z.avail_in > 0 || z.avail_out == 0);
    }
   
}
```